# Run function on interval in Processing

Tags: processing, intervals, mesh, timing, easing

I am working on a Processing sketch where draw a Delaunay diagram using points in a two dimensional array.
I generate the points in the array randomly, so now they are being generated very quickly as the `draw()` loop runs.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
  pX = random(nX);
  pY = random(nY);
  points[i][0] = pX;
  points[i][1] = pY;
}
```

I want to generate these numbers every 1 second for example. I tried with the following code, but the lines are being drawn only for a very short time every 1 second, and the interval seems to vary...

```java
if (millis() - timeCheck > timeInterval){
  for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    timeCheck = millis();

    pX = random(nX);
    pY = random(nY);

    points[i][0] = pX;
    points[i][1] = pY;
  }
}
```

My ultimate goal is to have lines shifting between old and new points as they are being generated. I want to use easing so the whole thing looks nice and smooth.

Here is the entire code. I use the [mesh library](http://leebyron.com/mesh/) for drawing the mesh.

```java
import megamu.mesh.*;
import processing.svg.*;
import processing.pdf.*;

  boolean recording = false;
  void rec() {
    if (key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
      recording = !recording;
    }
  }

  float numX;
  float numY;

  float x;
  float y;

  float offset = 0.00;
  float easing = 0.05;

  Delaunay myDelaunay ;

  int timeCheck;
  int timeInterval = 1000;

void setup(){

  size(600,400);

  timeCheck = millis();

}

void draw(){

  rec();
  if (recording){
    beginRecord(SVG, "####.svg");
  }

  offset = offset + .005;
  background(noise(offset) * 50);
  stroke((noise(offset) * 255)+100, (noise(offset) * 100)+50, noise(offset) * 255);

  float[][] points = new float[10][2];

  numX = (width);
  numY = (height);

  float nX = noise(offset) * width;
  float pX = random(nX);
  float targetX = random(nX);
  float dX;

  float nY = noise(offset) * height;
  float pY = random(nY);
  float targetY = random(nY);
  float dY;

  if (millis() - timeCheck > timeInterval){
    for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
      timeCheck = millis();
      //println(timeCheck);

      pX = random(nX);
      pY = random(nY);

      points[i][0] = pX;
      points[i][1] = pY;

    }
  }

  myDelaunay = new Delaunay( points );

  float[][] myEdges = myDelaunay.getEdges();

    for(int i=0; i<myEdges.length; i++) {

      dX = targetX - pX;
      x += dX * easing;
      dY = targetY - pY;
      y += dY * easing;

      float startX = myEdges[i][0];
      float startY = myEdges[i][1];
      float endX = myEdges[i][2];
      float endY = myEdges[i][3];
      line( startX, startY, endX, endY );
      ellipse(startX, startY, 5, 5);
  }

  endRecord();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to slow down the rate of calling the entire draw loop, `frameRate()` is your pal. It takes in an integer parameter as the number of times per second the draw loop is called. It defaults to 60, but calling that can change it to whatever you want. I just put this here on the off-chance this is what you wanted.

If you want the same frame rate, but to only have the for-loop occur once in a while, use modulus division. Processing stores the number of times the `draw()` loop was called as a variable called `frameCount`. You could use modulus division like so to make it such that your loop is only called once per second:

```java
if(frameCount % 60 == 1){//such that you generate the values on frame 1, and every 60th frame after that, assumes the frame rate is 60 fps.
    for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
        pX = random(nX);
        pY = random(nY);
        points[i][0] = pX;
        points[i][1] = pY;
    }
}
```

Link for more information about `frameRate()` is [here](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html).

Comment: Is there a reason you used `frameCount % 60 == 1` instead of `frameCount % 60 == 0`?

Comment: @KevinWorkman It was my impression that after calling `draw()`, `frameCount = 1`, so having `frameCount % 60 == 1` would allow the points to be generated in the first iteration of `draw()`.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. `frameRate()` is definitely not not I was looking for, `frameCount()` and the modulo OK results, but really the problem was that I was not declaring the variables at the right place. All my variables that contained random numbers were declared within the draw loop, when I should have declared them earlier, before the setup loop. Now the solution with `millis()` works fine! I will be posting a full answer when I am done with the project, but feel free to add. Thanks!